# Silex saving variable on middleware and acces it on controller

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, middleware, silex

I need to get a variable from before on silex, and access it outside the middleware :

```
 $app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    if ($request->getMethod() !== "OPTIONS") {
        $bearer = $request->headers->get('Authorization');
        $app["bearer"] = $bearer; 
        echo $app["bearer"]; // Works and display value
    }
    return null;
}, Application::EARLY_EVENT);
echo $app["bearer"]; // Don't works, Display "" :'(
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (miss) expecting the value before it's really defined. You do:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    if ($request->getMethod() !== "OPTIONS") {
        $app["bearer"] = $request->headers->get('Authorization');
    }
    return null;
}, Application::EARLY_EVENT);

echo $app["bearer"]; // WRONG!
```

Notice that you define the before middleware and immediately check for the *bearer* value. But in this step the middleware is not executed yet! The middleware is execute once you run `$app->run();`, before any controller. So in your controllers you can check for the value, but not before executing the `$app->run()` method (which triggers the middlewares). You could try, for exemple:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    if ($request->getMethod() !== "OPTIONS") {
        $app["bearer"] = $request->headers->get('Authorization');
    }
    return null;
}, Application::EARLY_EVENT);


$app->get('/some-route', function(Aplication $app) {
  echo $app["bearer"]; // Right!
});
```